# Filter not showing entries in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

In the attached Excel sheet the first columns have filters that show the right options.  The columns for the dates only show for the filter "Select All".  Filter by color is also off.  For example, if I try to filter for all the rows in 9 Apr that are non blank, the entries are not shown. Why is that?

[image]

The Excel sheet is accessible here:

[Filter.xlsm](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1URYJ8SXnznhdKNSxLjzUz1DebZWlQXin)

Comment: Difficult to pin down the issue,, better share the file on cloud or Drop box to examine to fix the issue !!'

Comment: See the worksheet in the description.

Comment: ,, I've downloaded & examine the Sheet, in fact you have applied FILTER without selection adequate rows, select all rows including column header and apply Filter,, it's working ☺

Comment: No it doesn't.  You don't need to select anything to apply a filter.  The filter works for columns like Team Type.  But if you try to filter for 2-Apr in that date column, the options are not listed.

Comment: Hi @user823527,, in col Q, R & S ,, Start, Actual & Planned Date does't have date 02 Apr !!,, Tell me the Col Name & Header where U r finding as issue !!